# Move to a position in a ListView and animate the cell

Tags: java, android, listview, animation

I'm trying to implement an animation to move to a position in a ListView and then animate the target cell.
My problem is that when using smoothScrollToPosition() dont know how to guess when the animation has ended.
I have tested and for very high amounts of entries in the listview the animation can take a lot of time so is not possible to set a prefixed amount of miliseconds to wait

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPositionFromTop%28int,%20int,%20int%29) overloaded function, seems like it has a `duration` parameter...

If that doesn't work, try the `OnScrollListener` to listen for scrolling events.